# If there is an polynomial time approximation to an NP-complete problem, is P approximately NP?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, np-complete, np, p-vs-np

Deciding bipartite hypergraph coloring is NP-hard:

> While for bipartite graphs a 2-coloring can be found in linear time, it was shown by Lovasz [10] that the problem to decide whether a given k-uniform hypergraph is bipartite is NP-complete for all `k≥3`.

Bipartite hypergraphs are colorable in expected (average) polynomial time:

> The purpose of this note is to present an algorithm that colors a hyper-graph chosen uniformly at random from the family of all labeled, 3-uniform, bipartite hypergraphs on `n` vertices in `O(n^5 * log (2n))` expected time.

Does this imply that P is approximately NP?

Source: https://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/home/schacht/abstracts/09eurocomb.pdf

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't prove that P = NP.

This has nothing to do with approximations; it has to do with [average-case hardness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average-case_complexity) vs [worst-case hardness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worst-case_complexity).  The two results are showing that solving the problem for a randomly chosen hypergraph is usually easy; but there exist hypergraphs where the problem is hard.  Presumably, choosing a hypergraph at random is very unlikely to give you one that's hard, but they do exist.

NP-completeness is about worst-case hardness: even if a problem is easy on average, it can still be NP-complete.

I have no idea what "P is approximately NP" would mean in any precise sense.

Comment: "choosing a hypergraph at random is very unlikely to give you one that's hard" How unlikely? What percent?

Comment: "This has nothing to do with approximations; it has to do with average-case hardness vs worst-case hardness. " Does that mean a polynomial *approximation* is worst-case polyonmial time, but sometimes answers incorrectly; a polynomial *expected* always answers correctly but worst-case time exceeds polynomial?

Comment: @WordsLikeJared, I recommend reviewing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_algorithm for definitions.  An approximation algorithm is one that has a guarantee on the quality of its output; a polynomial-time approximation algorithm is an approximation algorithm that runs in polynomial time, i.e., whose worst-case running time is polynomial.  (A PTAS or FPTAS is different.)

Comment: @WordsLikeJared, [negligible](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/11073/755) (smaller than one over any polynomial).